# Jsoup Not Parsing IFrame out of HTML

Tags: java, jsoup

Can anyone explain why jsoup is not picking up the iframe in the following html

```html
<div class="video">
<script class="video_preview_source" type="text/html">
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/109fdsagfa" id="campaign_video_7566" width="353" height="240" frameborder="0"></iframe></script>
<div class="video_preview"></div>
</div>
```

with this code

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = document.select("div.video script.video_preview_source iframe[src]");

System.out.println("elements:" + elements);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's not picking up the `<iframe />` as it is not expecting HTML inside a `<script />` tag. You need .data() to return the contents.

Also note: you can't select attributes directly, you will always get a full element in return.

Splitting all this, the following code works for me:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements =
            document.select("div.video script.video_preview_source");

Document iframeDoc = Jsoup.parse(elements.get(0).data());

Elements iframeElements = iframeDoc.select("iframe");

System.out.println(iframeElements.attr("src"));
```

Regards,
Alexander.

Comment: Thanks @ahus1 - thats exactly the code I was looking for. thank you for your help